# DualShock 4's trackpad is not working on 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, touchpad, bluetooth, gamepad

When I first paired my DualShock 4 wireless gamepad all features were working, I could use it as a gamepad in all applications and the gamepad's trackpad was working as a mouse.

I was having some connection issues with my computer's builtin Bluetooth hardware, so I decided to try a USB dongle. In order to use the dongle, I downloaded the Bluetooth manager from GNOME software since I couldn't choose which Bluetooth device to use in the GNOME's Bluetooth settings.

But when I paired using the manager, the trackpad stopped working. I decided to go back to the builtin GNOME Bluetooth manager, so I uninstalled the manager from GNOME software.

Unfortunately, the trackpad is still not working with GNOME's builtin Bluetooth manager. What might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to `Settings -> Devices -> Mouse and Touchpad`. Then turn on `Touchpad` option.